# Use previous data on ajax call

Tags: jquery

I've got a page that needs POST data to get an ajax response. The information relying on the POST data displays fine. However, after that, if the user wants to update some of the displayed data, I want to make another ajax call to update it on the fly. Then comes the problem as the first script doesn't get any POST data from the page that the user requests to update the information.

Right now I have this, which, obviously is giving me the problem

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            var uid = <?php echo $_POST['user_id']; ?>;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data : {user_id:uid},
                cache: false,
                url:"modules/user/showuserdata.php",                    
                success : function (data) {
                    $("#response").html(data);
                }
            })


        });

        $('#commit-changes').click(function(){

            $('#commit-user').submit();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $("#commit-user").serialize(),
                cache: false,
                url:"modules/user/updateuser.php",
                success : function(data){
                    $("#response-update").html(data);
                }

            })
        });
```

The javascript error that chrome outputs is

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

            var uid = <br />
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: user_id in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\inacesso\admin\edituser.php</b> on line <b>73</b><br />
;
```

I've ommited the html for a better reading, but if necessary please notice me.

Any hint on how I can bypass this? I didn't want to use SESSION variables...

Glad for all the help I can have on this.

EDIT

HTML response of the showuserdata.php

$user = new Users();

```
 $id = $_POST['user_id'];


 $rcs_user = $user->getUserByID($id);


 $rcs_roles = $user->getRoles();
 $role ='';
 foreach($rcs_roles as $roles)
 {
    if($roles->role_number == $rcs_user->permissao) 
        $role .= '<option value="'.$roles->role_number.'" selected="selected">'.$roles->role.'</option>';
    else
        $role.= '<option value="'.$roles->role_number.'">'.$roles->role.'</option>';
 }

 if($rcs_user->activo == 0)
 {
     $activo = '<input type="checkbox" name="activo" class="on_off_checkbox"  value="1"   />';
 }
 else
 {
     $activo = '<input type="checkbox" name="activo" class="on_off_checkbox" checked="checked"  value="1"   />';
 }


 $response = '';

 $response.='<form id="validation commit-user" action="" method="post"> 
                                <fieldset >
                                <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="'.$_POST['user_id'].'"/>
                                <legend>Actualizar Dados Utilizador</legend>
                                      <div class="section ">
                                      <label>Nome<small>Insira o seu nome</small></label>   
                                      <div> 
                                      <input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetterSp]] large" name="nome" id="f_required" value="'.utf8_encode($rcs_user->nome).'">
                                      </div>                                      
                                      </div>';
 $response.='<div class="section ">
                                      <label> Email<small>Insira o seu email</small></label>   
                                      <div> 
                                      <input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] large" name="email" id="e_required" value="'.  utf8_encode($rcs_user->email).'">
                                      </div>
                                      </div>';

 $response.= '<div class="section">
                                    <label>Permissões<small>Seleccione o tipo de utilizador </small></label>   
                                    <div>
                                        <select class="medium" name="role">

                                                   '.$role.'                                                 

                                        </select>       
                                  </div>
                                  </div>                                      
                                 <div class="section">
                                        <label>Activo<small>Activar utilizador</small></label>   
                                         <div>
                                            '.$activo.'
                                            <span class="f_help">ON / OFF  </span> 
                                        </div>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="section last">
                                  <div>
                                      <a href="" id="commit-changes" class="uibutton submit_form" name="submit">Submeter</a><a class="uibutton special"   onClick="ResetForm()" title="Limpar Formulário"   >Limpar Formulário</a>
                                 </div>
                                 </div>

                                </fieldset></form>';



   echo $response;
```

Comment: Your `uid` comes from PHP, and you make an AJAX call unconditionally.  Then why not produce the user data you want to show in the same PHP file you produce the `uid`?

Comment: Instead of using sessions you could simply inject a hidden element with the value of the user ID to be referenced on each page.

Comment: that looks like a php error, caused by you not sending in the user_id.  Make sure that the #commit-user form has a field with the name `user_id`

Comment: I've put an hidden element with the ID but the error persists.

Comment: To me, this seems like a situation where the user ID should be passed via the URL.

Comment: is the `$('#commit-changes')` function the one that does the "on-the-fly" updating?

Comment: @jessica yes, the second function should be responsible for that. After update, I want the first function to be recalled and show the updated information.

Comment: @JoãoDias ah.. that makes more sense. I'm still a bit confused, though. Why is the first function being regenerated after the AJAX call? If it's in the original page, wouldn't the javascript value already be output by the PHP after the second function call?

Comment: @jessica, no, the first function should be called every time the page loads. Because showuserinfo.php sends a form of the fields to be updated. 

IF, the user wants to update information, it alters the fields of the form (output from the first ajax call), then, the page should be re-generated with the updated data, without refresh.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12769/discussion-between-jessica-and-joao-dias)

Comment: @JoãoDias Right, but why is the javascript *function* regenerated, including the var uid line? Seems like that should not be part of the page that is regenerated?

Comment: @jessica, I see what you mean. I've a previous page that passes the user ID as argument. It's like a table with a list of users, which, if  I click on the edit link, it postes the user ID to this page, which, is then responsible to update the user's info if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that data is loaded through ajax calls.

I've solved this issue using .live or .on events of jQuery.

Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var params = [];

<?php if($_POST['user_id']): ?>
    params.user_id = <?php echo $_POST['user_id']; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data : params,
    cache: false,
    url:"modules/user/showuserdata.php",                    
    success : function (data) {
        $("#response").html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: And then, after update, how could I show the updated data on the user id?